# Working with the coupon collector problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, geometric-series, coupon-collector

Here is the problem I have:

Say that each box of cereal contains a prize. There are $n$ different prizes in all.

What is the probability that more than $t$ boxes are needed to find all $n$ gifts?

This is what I have worked out so far:

I know this is a variation on the coupon collector problem. I let $X$ be a random variable which is the number of boxes bought before all $n$ gifts are found. Finding $\Bbb E[X]$ is simple enough:

Let$$X=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$$

$$\text{Every $X_i$ is distributed geometrically, with probability of success $\frac{n-i}{n}$}$$
Now because each $X_i$ is independent we use the linearity of expectation: $$\Bbb E[X]=\Bbb E[X_1]+\Bbb E[X_2]+...+\Bbb E[X_n]$$
$$=1+\frac{n}{n-1}+\frac{n}{n-2}+...+n$$
$$=n(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n})$$
$$=n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i} $$
Now, how do I apply this to the question above to obtain $\Bbb P[X\geq t]?$ Apologies if this seems obvious.
Edit: Seemingly the expected value will not help to obtain the answer I'm looking for. I suppose what I need is the CDF of the random variable $X$. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think knowing $E[X]$ helps you much to find the probability in this case.  You might consider using the principle of inclusion and exclusion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: The expectation can't help you get the CDF, it can only provide a bound and not a very good one at that. You might be able to do it by thinking about the more general problem where $m/n$ of all boxes have no gift at all, and then reduce the size of the problem by conditioning on $X_1$. That is, $P(X \geq t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X \geq t \mid X_1=k) P(X_1=k)$, and now $P(X \geq t \mid X_1=k)$ is the probability that it takes at least $t-k$ draws in order to find $n-1$ gifts when $1/n$ of all boxes have no gift at all.

Comment: @Ian thanks for the answer, I suppose the expectation won't help me. Could you possibly give a more complete version of the answer you just gave?

Comment: Actually never mind, this way of doing it will ultimately just give you the general form $P(\sum_i X_i \geq t)=\sum_{\mathbf{x} : \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \geq t} \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i=x_i)$. Which doesn't directly help you to obtain any simple answer, all it does is convert it to $\sum_{\mathbf{x} : \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \geq t} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{n-i}{n} \left ( \frac{i}{n} \right )^{x_i-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the principle of inclusion exclusion,
\begin{align}
P(\text{more than $t$ boxes are needed})
&=P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{\text{prize # $i$ is missing}\}\right )
\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\hspace{-.7cm}\sum_{i(1)\le i(2)\le \dots\le i(k)}\hspace{-.7cm}P\Big(\text{prizes $i(1),i(2),\dots,i(k)$ are missing}\Big)
\\&=\boxed{\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k\left(1-\frac{k}n\right)^t.}
\end{align}

Comment: This could use a little bit of expansion to be clearer, I think.

Comment: @Ian Let $E_i^t$ be the event that after $t$ boxes are opened, prize number $i$ is missing. The second expression is $$P\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nE_i^t\right),$$ and the third is $$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\hspace{-.7cm}\sum_{i(1)\le i(2)\le \dots\le i(k)}\hspace{-.7cm}P\Big(E_{i(1)}^t\cap E_{i(2)}^t\cap \dots \cap E_{i(k)}^t\Big).$$ This is exactly how you apply principle of inclusion exclusion to compute the probability of a union of events. It should now be obvious why this evaluates to the fourth expression; we have fixed a particular set of $k$ prizes, and want the probability none are found.